# How can we use two OnClick Listener

Tags: android, android-intent

In my activity I want to use `import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and `import android.view.View.OnClickListener` because in my Activity I'm using both button and alert message. Anyone tell me how can I use both. While trying to import both `OnClickListeners` it's giving error. How to solve this issue??

Comment: Can you paste the error and some code snippet here?... So that someone can solve your problem easily.

Comment: you can set the id of the dialog and then onClick based on that id you can perform the required operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use complete package for either one of the listener like one as

```
           android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

and other as just

```
          OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 1):

Import one click listener and for another you can use by specifying absolute path in definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use like the following code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

For the button OnClick method, You need the following import,

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


alert_dialog.setPositiveButton("Button Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Dialog clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            }
        });
```

For the dialog OnClick method, You need the following import,

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Have u copied and tried this. You should be aware of importing. Copy and try this.
this is what works for many people. Its a working sample...